# String array binary search for a character

Tags: java, binary

I have this project that requires a user to input a string and then you're supposed to search through string for a character and the number of times it appears. I'm having trouble starting the search process using a binary algorithm for a character. This is what I got so far:

```
package assignment3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class charSearch{

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Scanner thisString=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello there! Please type in a few words and enter 'Done' when you are finished");

        String line=thisString.nextLine();

        String[] lineArray=line.split("\\ ");

        int lengthOfString=lineArray.length;

        String terminator="Done";

        String[] newArray=new String[lengthOfString-1];

        for(int i=0; i<lengthOfString-1; i++){

            if(lineArray[i]!=terminator){

                newArray[i]=lineArray[i];

                System.out.println(newArray[i]);

            }

        }

        int lengthOfArray=newArray.length;

    }

}
```

Comment: I see a potential error `if(lineArray[i]!=terminator)` it should be `if(!lineArray[i].equals(terminator))`. Having said that, what is the problem? where is the search algorithm?

Comment: You can't use a binary search with unsorted content. Why not just do a linear scan?

Comment: Your array copy logic is flawed.  it will copy all words except "Done", even ones occurring after "Done".  You need to count the owrds up to "Done" before sizing the final array.  Or just use some type of list that will automatically grow (like ArrayList).  Your requirements (count the letters) also does not require a binary search.

Comment: Your question is unclear.Post what you want to get exactly as a output.What are you trying and where you fail.

Comment: Actually the reason why the code is so basic is because this is for an introductory course to java and I didn't want to drift too far away from the material that we have covered so far. I actually went the route of a linear search instead of a binary. I thought we had to stick with binary but didn't have to. So I got the code to work. Thank you guys for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for if I do understand what you trying to get is something o this sort ?

```
package snippet;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snippet {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    countCharacters();
}

private static void countCharacters() {

    Scanner thisString = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello there! Please type in a few words and enter 'Done' when you are finished");

    String line = "", lettersToSearchFrom = "";

    while (!("Done").equals(line)) {

        line = thisString.nextLine();

        lettersToSearchFrom += line;
    }

    thisString.close();

    //Since "Done" takes up 4 characters, it will be removed
    int beginPoint = lettersToSearchFrom.length()-4;
    int endPoint = lettersToSearchFrom.length();

    //Replaces the last line entered which is "Done" as its not part of the letters to search from
    char[] characters = lettersToSearchFrom.toLowerCase().substring(0,beginPoint).toCharArray();

    System.out.println(lettersToSearchFrom);

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    //This is where the counting happens
    for (char key : characters) {

        if (map.containsKey(key)) {

            int frequency = map.get(key);
            frequency++;
            map.put(key, frequency);
        } else {
            map.put(key, 1);
        }

    }

    // Display frequency for each character ignoring case
    for (Entry<Character, Integer> item : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(item.getKey() + " = " + item.getValue());
    }

    //To display the frequency of a specific character you can just retrieve from map
    //The following is if we searching specifically for "A" and not "a"
    //Please keep in mind that everything was made to lower case so a '0' should be return for value of "A"
    //since it is not contained

    int frequency = map.get("A")==null?0:map.get("A");

    System.out.println("Number of occurences for 'A' is "+frequency);

}
}
```